# Absolute Configuration in Stereochemistry

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

I got all the rules of writing RS nomenclature for Perspective formula of chirality center only problem being, I m confused that given compound can have any configuration depending on how I write the perspective formula.
[image][image] It's basically Same Molecule

Comment: You need to get a physical model ... match sticks and blue-tac with paper labels / straws and blue-tac with paper labels build it and see if you can see it ... all your angles are supposed to be 109 ° are they in the second diagram?  (You'll see when you build it).

Comment: Not necessarily the same molecule.

Comment: the problem is that u are focussing on the theoritical aspect of it.u r just using wedge-dash concept.try converting it into fischer form(in the correct way), and u will see that there is only 1 way doing so, and hence the same molecule.

Comment: Keep bonds of the same type together. In structure 1, the Br and its bold bond should be flipped to the right just above the dotted hydrogen, similar to structure 2.

Comment: @user55119 is that a rule?

Comment: @granthium i want to apply rules to perspective formula only as i mentioned in my question

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne can you elaborate

Comment: @user1945827 i know what u are sayin, but question is can i apply rs rules to any compound or there is some kind of restriction

Comment: It is not a rule but it surely makes the picture more understandable. The structures in the answer are good models.

Answer (score 2):

You're right, the two compounds you depicted are basically the same molecule except for in their chirality. They are, essentially, *[enantiomers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enantiomer)* of each other.

In the slightly clearer depiction below,
[image]

by the [Cahn-Ingold-Prelog convention](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Organic_Chemistry/Supplemental_Modules_(Organic_Chemistry)/Chirality/Absolute_Configuration%2C_R-S_Sequence_Rules) we would call the molecule on the left ***S**-bromochlorofluoromethane*, while the one on the right would be its *R*-enantiomer, i.e. ***R**-bromochlorofluoromethane*.

Comment: i get this , this wasn't exactly the question. question is that i can change the configuration of same molecule by adjusting how i draw the solid wedge

Comment: @ManRow what software do u use to create such structures?

Comment: @ManRow didn't create it . He just used [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bromochlorofluoromethane).